# Vaadin horizontal layout

Tags: layout, vaadin

I have horizontal layout with 4 components : combobox, textField1 , textField2 and checkbox. Based on checkbox textField2 is displayed or not.  When checkbox is set to false then textField2 is not visible. How to prevent textField1 from expanding? I would like to have fixed position for components.. if checkbox or textField2 is not displayed others remaining in page would still look the same.So prevent from expanding to remaining space for component with horizontal layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way would be to put the field you want to hide inside another layout that has a fixed size and remains visible. Something like this:

```
    VerticalLayout textField2Layout = new VerticalLayout(textField2);
    textField2Layout.setWidth("200px");
    VerticalLayout verticalLayout = new VerticalLayout(combobox,textField1,textField2Layout,checkbox);
```